# Substring before and after xpath - using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrap a list of movies:

```
import scrapy
class ScrapeMovies(scrapy.Spider):
    name='movies-to-see'

    start_urls = [
        'https://www.listchallenges.com/200-movies-to-see-before-you-die/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for film in response.xpath('//div[@class="item-click-area"]'):
            yield{
                'year': film.xpath('substring-before(substring-after(.//div[@class="item-name"]/text(), '('), ')')').extract()
                'title': film.xpath('.//div[@class="item-name"]/text()').extract()[0].strip(),
                'rank': film.xpath('.//div[@class="item-rank"]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            }
```

On a desired page you have date and title of a movie stuck together. Using xpath i wanted to extract date which is in between parentheses. However i am constanlty recieving a syntax error. Why is that? Or maybe any other good ideas to scrap a year in which movie was created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should correctly mix single and double quotes in your XPath. Try

```
'substring-before(substring-after(.//div[@class="item-name"]/text(), "("), ")")'
```

Answer (score 0):

It have been a long time, but I share a code that worked for me.

Full string:

```
element.xpath('//nodes/text()').extract()
['BeforeText-WantedText-AfterText']
```

With substring before and after:

```
element.xpath('substring-before(substring-after(//nodes/text(), "BeforeText-"), "-AfterText")').extract()
['WantedText']
```